# Memcached does not respect ordering of tuples

Tags: python, memcached

I am using `memcached` through `pylibmc`. I am saving a tuple with four elements:

```
(A, B, C, D)
```

And reading the same key returns a different order:

```
(B, C, D, A)
```

My codebase is complicated, so the problem could be something else. I would like to know if there is a known issue with `memcached` and tuples before I spend more time investigating this.

Comment: Please show exactly how you are saving and retrieving the data.

Comment: Well, that's the point: looking for that will take me some time. I wanted to know beforehand if there is an already known issue - to implement a workaround. Since it seems there is no issue with tuples/memcached/pylibmc, it must be a bug in my code, which I must now search.

Answer (score 2):

It won't be `memcached` causing the problem as all it stores is the raw data it's sent. It doesn't understand data structures within the values it stores and certainly doesn't mess around with them.

`pylibmc` could feasibly cause the problem if its serialization/deserialization logic was flawed, but I would be absolutely amazed if this was the case.

If you want to rule `pylibmc` out, you could serialize the data yourself before passing it on directly to memcached (by perhaps using something like the `json` or `cPickle` libraries).